# An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT NEXTVAL('person_id_seq')':

Tags: api-platform.com

I have got a problem when I am trying to use the API -> HTTPS page to use my own entity that I have generated via schema-generator. the error that Im encountering is ='

An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT NEXTVAL('person_id_seq')':

SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "person_id_seq" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT NEXTVAL('person_id_seq')'

I have generated class Persone which inherit from Thing but when I try make a post request to create a new person I ve got this error. What im wondering  : am I supposed to create datatable something ? Please helpme with this problem any help is appreciated. Thank you

I have tried to use the answers that has been added on stackoverflow but it did not work.

Problem is solved !!

To have api-plateform working on your local do the next steps.

**Step 1**
For those who use Docker toolkit
-- To have localhost working go on virtualbox and click on the 'default' (which is in use by docker toolkit) and go on network tab and add the port that are being used with api-plateform like
 (8080,80,81..) like following image
[image]

its in turkish bu you'll surely understand ;)

-- **Step 2**
Go on your docker kid and go on your project directory where your api-plateform is project is placed.
then do the following

docker-compose exec php bin/console doctrine:schema:create --dump-sql
(to see your schema's needs that must be run)
then
docker-compose exec php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force

its okay resolved now you can work with api-plateform's API http plateform

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved !!

To have api-plateform working on your local do the next steps.

Step 1 For those who use Docker toolkit -- To have localhost working go on virtualbox and click on the 'default' (which is in use by docker toolkit) and go on network tab and add the port that are being used with api-plateform like (8080,80,81..) like following image enter image description here

its in turkish bu you'll surely understand ;)

-- Step 2 Go on your docker kid and go on your project directory where your api-plateform is project is placed. then do the following

docker-compose exec php bin/console doctrine:schema:create --dump-sql (to see your schema's needs that must be run) then docker-compose exec php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force

its okay resolved now you can work with api-plateform's API http plateform